# ClickOnce and both Update and Install folder

Tags: configuration, clickonce

I'm refactoring some msbuild scripts for a project, that uses ClickOnce to package the application. The project packages both an install and an update version  and puts then in seperate folders on the webserver. Any reason for this? The only difference when publishing the ClickOnce package, the the publish url (e.g. somesite.com/update and somesite.com/install).

I'm not an ClickOnce expert, but would it not be enough with just a single folder og both installing the client and updating it?

Thanks in advance.

NB. The update url always points towards the update folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is enough to have single folder for installing and updating application. ClickOnce will do everything automatically. The only thing is that when publishing the application, you have to specify what will be the update url (and it can be exactly the same as install url)...so basically, you can give your clients that "update" url as a location from where they can install the application.